slam_toolbox build source disable rvizXXX dependence
I tested slam_toolbox in x86_64 is working. Next step is porting to my ARM64 target platform by Yocto project which is wayland base QT5 and without X11
AFAIK, ROS2/rviz2 highly dependence on X11 system, Is any way to disable rvizXXX dependence from slam_toolbox.
Regards
Peter

QT5 has natively supported wayland for many years. But I don't know what dependencies might be coded into rviz2.
